# 1600 gallon water tank 50 feet above and 1000 feet away from use point, psi?

Tags: water

What size pipe should I use to obtain 40-50 psi for use in the house? I would use a poly pipe or pvc from the tank to house

Comment: https://www.pipeflow.com/pipe-pressure-drop-calculations

Comment: In a static case you'll obtain the psi of the static (water) head. In the dynamic case you'll have frictional losses due to pipe flow. Investigate pipe flow and cypher for yourself the pressure drop calculations to choose your assembly. Every component will have an effect and determine your ultimate flow.

Comment: https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/darcy-weisbach-equation-d_646.html will give you an idea for the straight line losses. Continue poking around to include angled fittings and valving.

Answer (score 1):

[image: diagram]

Assuming your system is something like this (and static), you will also need the height of the water in the container ($h_2$). What you are looking for is the hydrostatic pressure which only depends on the height, density of the fluid and gravity.

*Also try to use metric and convert back as needed as this makes the calculations easier.*

Let's assume the total height is $h=h_1+h_2=15.24[m]$ or $50 [ft]$. The hydrostatic pressure at point 2 will be:
$$P_2=\rho g h$$ where density ($\rho$) is approximately 1000[$kg/m^3$], and g is of course 9.81 [$m/s^2$].

This gives a hydrostatic pressure (gauge pressure) of 149504 [$Pa$] or 21.68 [$psi$].

Based on this info, to reach the desired pressure, you can either get a pump to increase the pressure or increase the height of the water container.